# Один и тот же шрифт по-разному выглядит в браузере и в макете

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, шрифты, photoshop

После подключения к странице указанного в фотошопе шрифта, он применился, так как стал похож на вариант в макете, но почему-то буква "i" в верхнем регистре в макете без засечек, а в браузере с засечками. В чём может быть причина?

Comment: В том, что браузер по-своему рендерит нестандартные шрифты. Более того, разные браузеры могут по-разному отрисовывать один и тот же нестандартный шрифт

Comment: Спросите дизайнера что он там наворотил. Скорее всего использовал какой-нибудь альтернативный вариант глифа.